# Why are my dates not equivalent in R when they look identical?

Tags: r, date, comparison

I have two dates in R - that have been created by rounding other dates to the nearest month start using lubridate::floor_date

They look identical under all sorts of tests... e.g.

> ymd(changes3$M[32])
> [1] "2020-08-01"
> ymd(changes3$M[33])
> [1] "2022-08-01"

> as.POSIXct(changes3$M[33])
> [1] "2022-08-01 01:00:00 BST"
> as.POSIXct(changes3$M[32])
> [1] "2020-08-01 01:00:00 BST"

but I cannot make them perform as equivalent e.g.

> changes3$M[32]==changes3$M[33]
> [1] FALSE

> as.POSIXct(changes3$M[32])==as.POSIXct(changes3$M[33])
> [1] FALSE

> round_date(as.POSIXct(changes3$M[32],day))==round_date(as.POSIXct(changes3$M[33],day))
> [1] FALSE

> format(changes3$M[33],"%Y%M")==format(changes3$M[32],"%Y%M")
> [1] FALSE

What might be going wrong? When I test them against themselves these methods work OK
e.g.

> as.POSIXct(changes3$M[32])==as.POSIXct(changes3$M[32])
> [1] TRUE

- so I am presuming it is something hidden in the Date format that I can't spot?

Answer (score 2):

That is a variant of [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) as *datetime objects really are floating point* valued.  The fact that a formatted display is equal only means that
you are (implicitly) truncating -- you need to make that implicit.

```
> now <- Sys.time(); notnow <- Sys.time()  # so microseconds apart
> format(now) == format(notnow)            # "looks the same"
[1] TRUE
> trunc(now) == trunc(notnow)              # "equal if truncated"
[1] TRUE
> round(now) == round(notnow)              # "equal if rounded"
[1] TRUE
> 
> now == notnow                            # but not equal numerically
[1] FALSE
>
```

While this may be a little irritating to work with, it is actually a *feature* as it gives some high(-ish) precision date and time comparison.

Comment: OK, thanks....
The next question then, is how can I get them to be treated as equivalent, when the trunc() and round() options you have illustrated with don't work...
e.g.

> trunc(changes3$M[33])==trunc(changes3$M[32])

[1] FALSE

> round(changes3$M[33])==round(changes3$M[32])

[1] FALSE


Also - as I created these dates using lubridate::floor_date() with the unit parameter set to "months"I would have imagined that the floor would have been exactly the same for any dates in the same month

Comment: charges3[,M:=floor_date(d,unit="months")]

Comment: Your example are not reproducible as we do not have your data but it seems that you need to decide at what granularity you do, or do not, want equality and then round or truncate accordingly.